# Is that application smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Having an application $f:(t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon)\backslash\{t_0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ in $C^{\infty}((t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon)\backslash\{t_0\})$ with $|f(t)|=1,\forall t\in (t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon)\backslash\{t_0\}$ and knowing that:

$\exists\ \lim\limits_{t\nearrow t_0} f(t)= -\lim\limits_{t\searrow t_0} f(t)=z_0$, we can define an other application $g:(t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon)\to\mathbb{C}$ by:

$$g(t)=\begin{cases} f(t),\ t<t_0 \\ z_0, \ t=t_0\\-f(t), t>t_0  \end{cases}$$

Is it true that $g\in C^{\infty}((t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon))$?

Comment: [Crossposted on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/206402/21564).

Comment: A little pointer about mathematical English: The object $f$ is called a _function_ or a _map_ or a _mapping_. The English word ["application"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/application?s=t) means something entirely different.

Comment: Thanks a lot for teaching me! I will use mapping from now on. My geometry teacher told me that the term function is used to describe real valued mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If
$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}
  -e^{it^{2}} & \text{if $t > 0$,} \\
   e^{-it^{2}} & \text{if $t < 0$,}
\end{cases}
$$
then $f$ is *analytic* on each subinterval $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$, but
$$
g(t) = \begin{cases}
  -f(t) & \text{if $t > 0$,} \\
  1 & \text{if $t = 0$,} \\
  f(t) & \text{if $t < 0$,} \\
\end{cases}
$$
i.e, $g(t) = e^{it|t|}$, isn't even of class $C^{2}$ at $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have modified the statement. I think now it should be ok. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279140/smooth-function-from-function-with-singularity