# Smooth function from function with singularity

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Having an application $f:(t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon)\to\mathbb{C}$ in $C^{\infty}((t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon))$ with $f(t)=0\Leftrightarrow\ t=t_0$ and knowing that:

$\exists\ \lim\limits_{t\nearrow t_0} \dfrac{f(t)}{|f(t)|}= -\lim\limits_{t\searrow t_0} \dfrac{f(t)}{|f(t)|}=z_0$, we can define an other application $g:(t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon)\to\mathbb{C}$ by:

$$g(t)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{f(t)}{|f(t)|},\ t<t_0 \\ z_0, \ t=t_0\\ -\dfrac{f(t)}{|f(t)|}, t>t_0  \end{cases}$$

Is it true that $g\in C^{\infty}((t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon))$?

Comment: Something looks awry: Since $|z_{0}| = 1$, don't the limit conditions guarantee $g$ isn't even continuous at $t_{0}$...?

Comment: @user86418 Of course. Sorry for the typo...I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Again, take $t_{0} = 0$. We may write
$$
f(t) = r(t) e^{i\theta(t)}
$$
with $r \geq 0$ and $\theta$ real-valued functions of $t$ (and $r(t) = 0$ if and only if $t = 0$), so that
$$
\frac{f(t)}{|f(t)|} = e^{i\theta(t)}.
$$

If we take $r$ to be the continuous extension of $r(t) = e^{-1/t^{2}}$ and
$$
\theta(t) = \begin{cases}
  -t & \text{if $t < 0$,} \\
   t + \pi & \text{if $t > 0$,} \\
\end{cases}
$$
then
$$
\lim_{t \nearrow 0} e^{i\theta(t)} = 1 = -\lim_{t \searrow 0} e^{i\theta(t)},
$$
and
$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}
  e^{-1/t^{2}} e^{-it} & \text{if $t < 0$,} \\
  0 & \text{if $t = 0$,} \\
  -e^{-1/t^{2}} e^{it} & \text{if $t > 0$,} \\
\end{cases}
$$
is of class $C^{\infty}$ even at $0$, but $g(t) = e^{i|t|}$ is not of class $C^{1}$ at $0$.

Comment: Now, I see. We need extra condition for $f$ at $t_0$. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: You're welcome; sorry not to have better news.... :) (Offhand, it looks as if you assume $f$ is _real-analytic_ you may get somewhere; that prevents the vanishing-to-infinite-order behavior in this example, so if $\theta$ fails to be real-analytic, so does $f$. Haven't thought too carefully about this, though.)

Comment: Yes, in that case it's indeed true. $g$ will have a compact formula.